# How to connect to existing SQLite DB using tortoise ORM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, tortoise-orm

I have existing SQLite DB with large data in it. I want to query the data asynchronously using tortoise ORM. How do I connect the database and query the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is not magical tool. The `inspectdb` option in [Aerich](https://github.com/tortoise/aerich) works for `mysql`.
You can create your `models` and read data from old `sqlite` db by [driver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and insert into new database.

The `bulk_create` method can improve the process time.